# Rerouting Mobile Data Connection as WiFi (Fake-WiFi)

Tags: wi-fi

I have data connection (via `rmnet0` interface)

Is it possible to reroute it as WiFi (via `wlan0` interface), so that it is detected as WiFi connection by some apps?

I tried the [Fake Wifi Reworked](http://repo.xposed.info/module/eu.chylek.adam.fakewifi) Xposed module, it didn't work on Nougat.

Is there a way to do it via shell from ADB or Terminal?

**What I tried:**

```
su -c ifconfig wlan0 0.0.0.0
```

(To reach the local IPv4 address) But it didn't help.

Or is modifying it at the Android API level the only way to achieve this? (Like how the Xposed module does)